# Oracle SQL. Time between states

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a table like this:

State || Date; 00 || Date1; 60 || Date2; 00|| Date3; 60 || Date4...always exist the 00 state and then the 60, is a sequence. But i cant know how many times the sequence is repeted. Maybe one time, or two, like in the example, or three, or four...

I need to calculate the total time between estates 00 and 60, i.e. (Date2-date1)+ (Date4-Date3)+...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you are expecting but it will subtract the next date with the current date for states which are 00. Also please be specific in your question what u exactly need

```
select id,trunc(next_day - day) from 
(select id,day,lead(day) over (order by day) next_day
from date_test)
where id = '00';
```

Comment: One column is named States and de rows could be 00,60,00,60,00,60...and the other column are the dates when the state is created....Date1, date2, date3, date4, date5...And i nedd to calculate the time between first state 60 and 00, then the time between the second state 60 and 00, and so on, and then sum all of this partial times.